# SFINAE error on VS2013?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, visual-studio-2013

I've been trying just about anything I could think of to get the `_CallWithRightmostArgsInner` function to properly fail so that SFINAE could work properly and with this attempt, VS2013 has given me the error:
`error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,void>'`

Any ideas?  Is there an alternative that would be better?  The idea here is that I would like to make a function call to Function provided that Function takes a number or parameters as denoted by NumArgs.  The last two variadic arguments should be forwarded to the function and the result returned.

```
template <typename Function, int NumArgs>
class SplitParameters {
public:
    typedef typename function_traits<Function>::result_type result_type;

    template <typename ... RightArgs>
    static result_type CallWithRightmostArgs(const Function& call, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(RightArgs) >= NumArgs, "Unable to make function call with fewer than minimum arguments.");
        return _CallWithRightmostArgs(call, std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
    }

private:
    template <typename ... RightArgs>
    static result_type _CallWithRightmostArgs(const Function& call, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
        return _CallWithRightmostArgsInner(call, std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
    }

    // note the '==' vs '!=' in these two functions.  I would assume that only one could exist
    template <typename LeftArg, typename ... RightArgs, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(RightArgs) != NumArgs>::type* = 0>
    static result_type _CallWithRightmostArgsInner(const Function& call, LeftArg, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
        return _CallWithRightmostArgs(call, std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
    }

    template <typename LeftArg, typename ... RightArgs, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(RightArgs) == NumArgs>::type* = 0>
    static result_type _CallWithRightmostArgsInner(const Function& call, LeftArg, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
        return call(std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Here are my few tries on ideone (using gcc 4.8) and I hit the same error: http://ideone.com/O9Wnd6 ; note: you should not ignore `LeftArg` when counting the number of arguments, and it should be `LeftArg&&` to avoid copying (even when you ignore it), I patched those issues in the ideone version.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good point with the ref -- I looked it over since that variable is unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working for g++-4.8 by changing your code to

```
    #include <iostream>

    template <class T>
    struct function_traits
    {
        typedef void result_type;
    };

    template <typename Function, int NumArgs>
    class SplitParameters {
    public:
        typedef typename function_traits<Function>::result_type result_type;

        template <typename ... RightArgs>
        static result_type CallWithRightmostArgs(const Function& call, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
            static_assert(sizeof...(RightArgs) >= NumArgs, 
                          "Unable to make function call with fewer than minimum arguments.");
            return _CallWithRightmostArgs(call, std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
        }

    private:
        template <typename ... RightArgs>
        static result_type _CallWithRightmostArgs(const Function& call, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
            return _CallWithRightmostArgsInner(call, std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
        }

        // note the '==' vs '!=' in these two functions.  I would assume that only one could exist
        template <typename LeftArg, typename ... RightArgs, class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(RightArgs) != NumArgs -1 >::type>
        static result_type _CallWithRightmostArgsInner(const Function& call, LeftArg, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
            return _CallWithRightmostArgsInner(call, std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
        }

        template <typename ... RightArgs, class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(RightArgs) == NumArgs>::type>
        static result_type _CallWithRightmostArgsInner(const Function& call, RightArgs && ... rightArgs) {
            return call(std::forward<RightArgs>(rightArgs)...);
        }
    };

    void f(int i, int j)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        SplitParameters<decltype(f), 2>::CallWithRightmostArgs(f, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    }
```

The compiler didn't like you calling `_CallWithRightmostArgs` from `_CallWithRightmostArgsInner`, and I assumed you were actually trying to call the `Inner` function.
g++ also didn't like converting `0` to `void*` in the template parameter list so I changed that to just be `class = enable_if<...>::type` instead.

I didn't look into the reasons it was failing in detail though, hopefully this is good enough for you.

**EDIT**:
With regards to the `typename enable_if<...>::type* = 0` being rejected, I remembered that there is a similar issue with `std::array`:

```
    template <class T, int size>
    void f(const std::array<T,size>&){}
```

This little snippet compiles just fine on its own, but when you do:

```
    std::array<int,4> a;
    f(a);

    g++ gives:
    test3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    test3.cpp:9:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(std::array<int, 4ul>&)’
         f(a);
            ^
    test3.cpp:9:8: note: candidate is:
    test3.cpp:4:6: note: template<class T, int size> void f(const std::array<T, size>&)
     void f(const std::array<T,size>&){}
          ^
    test3.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    test3.cpp:9:8: note:   mismatched types ‘int’ and ‘#‘integer_cst’ not supported by dump_type#<type error>’
         f(a);
            ^
    test3.cpp:9:8: note:   ‘std::array<int, 4ul>’ is not derived from ‘const std::array<T, size>’
```

The problem, as it turns out, is I declared the template as taking an `int` for the `size` parameter, but what the compiler got was a `std::size_t` which is not the same as an `int` and even though you can convert between them easily.
In the example above, I can't even replace `= 0` with `= NULL` because that's just a `0L` literal, I would have to do `= (void*)0` to get the compiler to accept it (because the default type of `enable_if<true>::type` is `void`).

Comment: And that seems to do it.  I wish I had an explanation as to why it failed previously, but I'm content enough with this solution.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the _CallWithRightmostArgs is no longer necessary and reduces the solution to three functions.

Comment: Do you happen to know why `class = typename enable_if` is required instead of just `typename enable_if ...`?

Comment: Depends on whether you mean `typename enable_if<...>::type* = 0` or `typename enable_if<...>::type`.  The second one doesn't properly name a template parameter, I believe the first doesn't work because the compiler doesn't do any type conversions when matching template parameters (this may be somewhat incorrect/worded poorly).  Using `typename enable_if<...>::type* = (void*)0` works.